# referencemanyfield returns all data from reference (not only the right ones)

Tags: react-admin

In React-Admin (v 4.2.4) I'm using 3 resources for a specific view (as showed in the following image also if there's a fourth table).
[image: Data structure and relationships]

In my JS file I have this component:

```
export const RichiestaMerceModifica = () => {
    return (
        <Edit actions={false} resource="richieste_merce_intestazioni">
            <SimpleForm toolbar={<CustomToolbar />}>
                <List actions={false} pagination={false}>
                    <ReferenceManyField reference="richieste_merce_dettagli" target="id_rm" source="id">
                        <Datagrid>
                            <TextField source="id_rm" />
                            <ReferenceField source="id_prod" reference="prodotti_acquisto" label="Prodotto">
                                <TextField source="nome" />
                            </ReferenceField>
                            <ReferenceField source="id_prod" reference="prodotti_acquisto" label="Descrizione" link={false}>
                                <TextField source="descr" />
                            </ReferenceField>
                            <TextField source="qta" label="Q.ta" />
                            <ReferenceField reference="prodotti_acquisto" source="id_prod" label="Imp. unitario" link={false}>
                                <FunctionField render={record => `${record.imp} €`} />
                            </ReferenceField>
                            <BooleanField source="ordinato" />
                        </Datagrid>
                    </ReferenceManyField>
                </List>
            </SimpleForm>
        </Edit>
    );
}
```

All required fields are shown correctly but in the List there are all records from **richieste_merce_dettagli** resource (not only the correct ones as expected, having defined **target="id_rm" source="id"**).

In the following image is shown the RichiestaMerceModifica Component and I'm in the view for ID 5 so in the List should be only products where "id rm" is 5.
[image]

In Admin component I have added

```
<Resource name="richieste_merce_dettagli" />
<Resource name="richieste_merce_intestazioni" options={{ label: 'Richieste Merce' }} list={RichiesteMerceList} icon={AddCircleOutline} create={RichiestaMerceNuovo} edit={RichiestaMerceModifica} />
<Resource name="prodotti_acquisto" options={{ label: 'Prodotti acquisto' }} list={ProdottiAcquistoList} icon={Summarize} create={ProdottoAcquistoNuovo} edit={ProdottoAcquistoModifica} />
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Look at your network tab. What request is fired to your API backend? Is there a non-empty filter query parameter? Did you implement the dataProvider.getManyReference() method correctly?

Comment: At page load there are 4 GET requests: 1st to /richieste_merce_intestazioni/5, 2nd  to /richieste_merce_dettagli?order=id%2CDESC&page=1%2C25&, 3rd to /richieste_merce_intestazioni?order=id%2CASC&page=1%2C10& and the last one to /prodotti_acquisto/2,3. To "richieste_merce_dettagli" endpoint no ID is passed so I think my problem is here because I get all 3 products instead of only 1. What do you mean for correct implementation of getManyReference()? If I use <ReferenceManyField> component is not enough? Does not it make the work independently (using getManyReference() method)?

Comment: The request to `/richieste_merce_dettagli` is missing a filter prop. This indicates that your dataProvider doesn't correctly handle them in the `getManyReference` method. Check your dataProvider and https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviderWriting.html#example-rest-implementation

Comment: I can't understand why I should write my own DataProvider. I'm using [php-crud-api](https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api) in relationship with [ra-data-treeql](https://github.com/nkappler/ra-data-treeql). For instance, ReferenceField works fine (I'm using it in different components) but ReferenceManyField not set the right "id_rm" in the request.

Comment: Simply including ```<Edit title={<TitoloSezione />} actions={false}><SimpleForm toolbar={<CustomToolbar />}><ReferenceManyField reference="richieste_merce_dettagli" target="id_rm" ></ReferenceManyField></SimpleForm></Edit>``` I can see in Network tab 2 requests: 1st to /richieste_merce_intestazioni/5 (and it's ok) and 2nd to /richieste_merce_dettagli (and all records of all orders are returned). Should not call /richieste_merce_dettagli/XX where XX is the "target" prop of <ReferenceManyField> ? Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to use a `<List>` component inside an `<Edit>` component. `<List>` and `<Edit>` are *page components*, and there can be only one per page.

The code should work without it:

```
export const RichiestaMerceModifica = () => {
    return (
        <Edit actions={false} resource="richieste_merce_intestazioni">
            <SimpleForm toolbar={<CustomToolbar />}>
-               <List actions={false} pagination={false}>
                    <ReferenceManyField reference="richieste_merce_dettagli" target="id_rm" source="id">
                        <Datagrid>
                            <TextField source="id_rm" />
                            <ReferenceField source="id_prod" reference="prodotti_acquisto" label="Prodotto">
                                <TextField source="nome" />
                            </ReferenceField>
                            <ReferenceField source="id_prod" reference="prodotti_acquisto" label="Descrizione" link={false}>
                                <TextField source="descr" />
                            </ReferenceField>
                            <TextField source="qta" label="Q.ta" />
                            <ReferenceField reference="prodotti_acquisto" source="id_prod" label="Imp. unitario" link={false}>
                                <FunctionField render={record => `${record.imp} €`} />
                            </ReferenceField>
                            <BooleanField source="ordinato" />
                        </Datagrid>
                    </ReferenceManyField>
-               </List>
            </SimpleForm>
        </Edit>
    );
}
```

Comment: Ok. I tried to remove the List component but no differences.